# There is an folder in my KDE Kickoff named Debian

Tags: kde, menu

I just recently reinstalled Debian Wheezy on one of my computers, now I've noticed that there is an folder named "Debian" in the list of applications in the Kickoff Application Launcher list. In this folder there is a totally different set of programs, some applications only show up in this folder.

Note my install was a fresh install.

Why do I have this folder in Kickoff and how to merge it into the default Kickoff lists (if possible)?

Here are pictures of the folder:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I did find [this](https://lists.debian.org/debian-qt-kde/2012/10/msg00119.html) bug, I've tried what is mentioned there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design.

Pairing applications with menus requires knowledge of both the menu structure and the list of applications. The author of a menu structure can't know about all the applications out there. The author of an application can't know about all the menus out there. Different menus have different groups, and prefer different applications — for example, when there is a Gnome application and a KDE application with a similar purpose, the KDE menu will typically show only the KDE application, while the Gnome menu will show only the Gnome application.

Debian provides a menu containing all the installed applications that declare a GUI menu entry. This is the “Debian” menu. Some of the applications in that menu are also available under Kickoff's own category system. The Debian menu is available under all desktop environments.

To merge the Debian menu into the Kickoff menu would require categorizing each application that isn't already there. Furthermore some non-KDE applications would be left out because there's a (supposedly better) KDE application. The KDE menu, like others, goes for a consistent user experience, not for completeness. The Debian menu is there for completeness.